# Unwinding Modal Segue before Root Navigation Controller - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Here are my View Controllers:

[image]

There is a modal segue between the initial view controller and the root of the navigation controller.

As you can see the Tab Views are sharing the 'Back' Button.

This is done through the navigation controller.

When I run the following command:

```
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

when 'Back' is clicked, nothing happens.

I believe this brings you back to the root of the Navigation Controller, which essentially does nothing.

So how do I make the 'Back' button bring me back to first, initial View Controller.

Thanks !

Comment: I've answered your question below, but have a comment which is out of context for the question; You should not place TabBarControllers inside NavigationControllers. You should do it the other way around

Comment: From what you said, you need to ask the presenter to do the dismiss which is the controller presenting the UINavigationController. So `self.navigationController.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`. As noted by @Spoek, you really want the tabs to contain navigation controllers, where each tab controller can push/pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwind by using an unwind segue.

Place this in your initial ViewController:

```
@IBAction func unwindToSegue (segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

And then ctrl-drag from your button to the "Exit" symbol of your TabViewController. The method `unwindToSegue` should show up, so pick it.